# Google Cloud Engine pull public docker image causes manifest unknown error

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to run a docker image on a gce vm instance. I changed the core count and checked the box for deploying a container image. In the container image box I put docker.io/urw7rs/spiralpp:latest.

When I create the vm, I get an error : Attempting next endpoint for pull after error: manifest unknown: Failed to fetch \"latest\" from request \"/v2/urw7rs/spiralpp/manifests/latest\

I tried changing docker.io to registry.hub.docker.com, checked allow http and https traffic in firewall. I also tried running without any command and command arguments.

[container options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKlnM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've reproduced your issue in my project and I found a workaround for this:

1. Please create a new instance using a Container-Optimized OS image.

Container-Optimized OS is an operating system image for your Compute Engine VMs that is optimized for running Docker containers, please refer to this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/create-configure-instance#simple) to know how to install it.

I suggest you to avoid steps 4, 5 and 6, so you can use the docker commands within the instance to pull the image.

Don't forget to choose the latest version of Container-Optimized OS during the VM instance creation, to achieve this; once you've clicked on the "create instance" button, please search for the "Boot disk" section and click on the "Change" button; then go to the operating system option and select "Container-Optimized OS" and adjust the Size (GB) of the disk, please leave the version by default.

2. Once the VM instance is ready, please SSH the instance.
3. Once you're inside the instance, please run this command:

docker pull urw7rs/spiralpp:latest

4. Please run this command to check the image is being downloaded to your instance.

docker images

Please let me know the results.